# While loop stops Timer from running (Dart)

Tags: flutter, dart, asynchronous, while-loop, timer

I have a question about while loop in dart.

This is a piece of code:

```
bool temp = false;
Timer(Duration(milliseconds: 5), () {
    print('In timer:' + temp.toString());
    temp = true;
});
Timer(Duration(milliseconds: 1000), () {
    print('In timer:' + temp.toString());
});
```

The result is exactly what I expect:

```
false (after 5 ms)
true (after 1 s)
```

But when add while loop:

```
bool temp = false;
Timer(Duration(milliseconds: 5), () {
    print('In timer:' + temp.toString());
    temp = true;
});

while (!temp) {}
print('End');
```

I expect that it will print out the console like this:

```
false
End (immediately after false)
```

But everything stucks in while loop and the timer doesn't seem to run to update temp anymore. May I get any explanation?

Comment: dart is single-threaded, so if you enter an infinite loop your app will be blocked forever

Answer (score 4):

Your while loop and timer are running in the same isolate, so your while loop blocks the event loop which prevents the timer from executing.

To learn more about the event loop and isolates, see [the official blog post](https://medium.com/dartlang/dart-asynchronous-programming-isolates-and-event-loops-bffc3e296a6a) or an [old but detailed article](https://web.archive.org/web/20170704074724/https://webdev.dartlang.org/articles/performance/event-loop).

Comment: Thank you. I see it now.